# In woocommerce some products have empty options, but how to check this

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, mysql

Our shop data is done by externals. They forget to put the options into some products. But these products do have options. There are more than 1000 products in the table. Testing it manually is not an option.

Can I create MYSQL script to check if there are products that should have options but are empty? So I get a list of products id.

Comment: what do you call "options". is that data put in meta of product ? if so, you can find these products with `get_post` : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts

Comment: hmm do not know what youre asking. here a screenshot of the options. http://prntscr.com/f2ud1s